# C - fscanf, format issues

Tags: c

I'm learning C now and need some help with the following:

I get as an input a file when its lines are in the following format:

```
file1.h: file3.sas,file7.txt,name.lll,..

file4.f: file6.kgl,...

...
```

I'm trying to get from each line the file's name (including ".h/.something").

So I read about fscanf and tried to use it as follows:

```
 fscanf(fpointer, "%[^:]", filesName);

 fscanf(fpointer, " %s", rest);
```

The problem is that `filesName` "catches" what I want and then catches the "rest" , and always `rest` doesn't catch anything.

Example for input and output:

input a file with the following lines:

```
file1.h: gri.ad,adsd.eda

file2.h: da.ad,dads.da
```

output:

```
filesName: file1.h 

rest: : 

filesName:  gri.ad,adsd.eda

file2.h 

rest: : 

filesName:  da.ad,dads.da 

rest: :
```

Where did I made a mistake?

Comment: please add an input output example

Comment: @DrPrItay thanks, i did.

Answer (score 2):

The first fscanf reads the filename and the second one reads just the colon (up until the whitespace). Then the "rest" is read as a part of the next filename.

Try this

```
 fscanf(fpointer, "%[^:]:", filesName);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the "rest" remains the same ?

Comment: If your "rest" has no embedded whitespace it should work, otherwise you need something else to read it...

Comment: ok, it seems to be batter -  now the second file's name is in a new line , why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all file names within the files (which is what I assume you actually want to do), pack reading into a loop:

```
char buffer[256];
char c;
int result;
do
{
    result = fscanf(file, "%255[^,]%c", buffer, &c);
    if(result > 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
}
while(result > 1);
```

Note that I added the buffer size to the package parameter for not exceeding buffer size (unfortunately, size cannot be passed via * as with printf...). Additionally, I read in the comma explicitely as character to be able to detect loop end (I used comma as this is what you posted in your input samples, put back colon if need be...).

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be your problem is your regular expressions

%s reads up to a whitespace - space / tab / newline and so what basically happens is that you are reading up to : unincluded and %s gets the : within itnstead.

Try this instead

`fscanf(fpointer, "%[^:]", fileName); // get everything up to :`

`fgetc(fpointer); // get rid of :`

`fgetc(fpointer); // get rid of space`

`fscanf(fpointer, "%[^\n]", rest); // get the entire line`

However this seems to me like a very unsecure solution that could easily be boffed
 Read more about regular expressions and scanf to find better solutions